# Разбить строку на массив, применить формулу к каждому элементу, вернуть конкатенацию результатов. Excel

Tags: excel

В одной ячейке записаны номера через разделитель. Нужно разбить строку на массив чисел. Под каждым номером найти букву в другой строке. Вернуть единую строку.

Например:

```
In: 5-8-12
Key: АнанасищеВкусный
Result: ащу
```

Сложность в том, чтобы сделать это формулой, а не через VBA

Comment: *сделать это формулой* Это злобный учитель такое условие родил?

Comment: Нет, это злобный я такое родил. В сущности, эксель - это ведь в первую очередь про формулы.

Comment: Такое возможно. Но придётся использовать две вспомогательные таблицы.

Comment: В том то и дело, что можно было бы вывести в отдельный столбец разбивку первой строки (в соответствии с номером строки в этом столбце вытаскивать в него подстроку от разделителя до разделителя). В соседнем столбце применить формулу (поиск символа в строке), а в последнем уже столбце сконкотенировать предыдущий. Но решение слишком не мобильное. Формула нужна из-за необходимости передавать её в сообщении мессенджера (например). Уже сталкивался с ситуациями, когда в формуле по сути обрабатывался цикл, но это слишком высокие материи для моего кунг-фу.

Comment: Почему мешает мобильности, если файл открыт и неважно, одна там формула или несколько? Нужно передавать формулу или результат? Что мешает при наличии доп. вычислений передавать только  нужное?

Comment: *Это могут быть 2 [ключа], а могут быть 99* === Не согласен с голосами за закрытие. Задача такой сложности учебным заданием быть не может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ПСТР(A3;ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК("-";A2)-1);1)&ПСТР(A3;--ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;"-";ПОВТОР(" ";50));50;50);1)&ПСТР(A3;--ПРАВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;"-";ПОВТОР(" ";50));50);1)
```

В *А2* - строка с числами, в *А3* - текст.

С виду страшненькая, на самом деле ничего сложного. Три части. Каждая часть - извлечение буквы:

```
=ПСТР(A3;позиция_буквы;1)
```

различия только в получении позиции буквы.

**Первое число**. Левая часть до разделительного знака:

```
=ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК("-";A2)-1)
```

**Второе число**. Тут небольшая хитрость. Меняем разделитель на много пробелов и извлекаем вторую часть с пробелами:

```
=--ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;"-";ПОВТОР(" ";50));50;50)
```

**Третье число**. Тот же прием, но извлекаем правую часть:

```
=--ПРАВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;"-";ПОВТОР(" ";50));50)
```

Двойное отрицание преобразует текст в число. Именно для этого разделитель заменялся на пробел, а не какой-либо другой символ: пробелы при преобразовании в число удаляются.

' ---------------------------------

**Если числовых ключей много** и их количество может быть разным, то составить текстовую строку одной формулой и только с применением функций листа не получится, т.к. текстовые функции при работе в массивах не умеют объединять значения массива.

Максимум, чего можно добиться - последовательно добавлять по одному символу, протянув формулу по строкам. Одной формулой, но не в одной ячейке. Два варианта такого решения:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(B1&ИНДЕКС(ПСТР($A$3;--ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ("-"&$A$2;"-";ПОВТОР(" ";99));СТРОКА($1:$9)*99;99);1);СТРОКА(A1));"")

=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A1)>ДЛСТР($A$4)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ($A$4;"-";))+1;"";C1&СТРОЧН(ИНДЕКС(ПСТР($A$3;--ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ("-"&$A$4;"-";ПОВТОР(" ";99));СТРОКА($1:$9)*99;99);1);СТРОКА(A1))))
```

"Не формулы массива", т.е. не требуют ввода тремя клавишами. *В1* и *С1* - ссылки на ячейку над формулой. Ячейка пустая.

Второе число в диапазоне *СТРОКА($1:$9)* задает максимальное количество ключей. Можно заменить на другое значение. Формулу нужно потягивать на количество строк, не меньшее количества ключей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столбец можно скрыть, результат отображать в отдельной ячейке:

```
=ИНДЕКС(B2:B9;ПОИСКПОЗ("?*";B2:B9;-1))
```

Comment: Нооо, почему обязательно три числа? 3 числа есть в примере, но не в вводной. Это могут быть 2, а могут быть 99. В этом вся сложность ._. Я убрал необходимость почистить строку чтобы как-то изолировать подзадачу, хотя там еще всё кроме цифр и разделителя надо убирать, но другая часть

Comment: О том, что чисел много, нужно было написать сразу. А то, что умолчали о чистке строки - это совсем никуда не годится. Упрощение условий - изменение задачи. Решение может быть совершенно другое. Дополните описание задачи. Но, похоже, одной формулой такое не решить. Массив чисел создать не проблема. И даже буквы можно в массиве показать. Но одной формулой объединить их в одну строку вряд ли получится. Текстовые функции ограничены в работе с массивами

Comment: Про количество чисел вообще ни слова не сказано, формальная логика никак не подсказывает, что их три =\ Задача без изменений - есть строка с разделителями, есть ключ, нужно вытащить буквы по номерам. Будет грустно, если одна формула не осилит, эх.

Comment: Да, про количество ничего не сказано. Как не сказано и о том, что их может быть не три. Зато пример есть.=====/Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Что ж, это лучший вариант. Думаю, вполне можно пользоваться, спасибо за помощь!